# Deploying symfony without shell access

Tags: php, symfony1, hosting, doctrine

Good day,

I have an application written using the Symfony framework.  The application works on my development server, where I have shell access.  However, I am unable to load my application on my host, as I need to run `symfony doctrine::build` on the command line on the host.

Is there another way to load the database after or during `symfony project:deploy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be building anything on the production environment - to deploy your SQL, use whatever tool you use to connect to the server, ie. SQLYog, PHPMyAdmin, etc. and use the SQL schema created by Doctrine in your dev environment. If you need fixtures too, you can always just dump the SQL schema and data from your dev database.

Consider that over a project lifecycle, you only really need to deploy the main SQL schema once - the rest is iterative via migrations.